# How to implement Diffie-Hellman between C# .Net and PHP

Tags: c#, php, .net, diffie-hellman

I have been tasked to implement Diffie-Hellman on a software that extracts and sends data through sockets from a Windows platform to a Linux server. I have developed a windows service in C# that sends data to a PHP script running as the server.

I have no knowledge of cryptography and have started studying DH for this project. I understand the methodology of the process and have found a way to implement it in PHP. However on the C# side, I can only find an [Elliptic-curve DH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/shawnfa/elliptic-curve-diffie-hellman) implementation which is different from my PHP implementation. If I understand things right, my PHP implementation is regular DH which uses a prime and generator as the public key pair. But ECDH is different in which it uses a curve and a point on that curve. I can find no regular DH implementation on .Net and have to decide on how to best implement DH on both ends.

I cannot seem to find much info on this and am hoping someone can help me. How would I go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: Don't understand the question you want an implementation or implement it yourself? Did you do a custom implementation for php or used some library? Please provide some examples of what isn't working.

Comment: We have a PHP implementation of non-EC DH as a cryptography API we use internally. I have to develop a C# equivalent so my windows service can exchange messages with a Linux server, though I can only find an Elliptic-curve DH implementation on .Net. Which to my understanding, are not compatible because the key pair is generated differently. I need to either do ECDH on PHP, or find a way to do non-EC DH on C#. Just need some pointers to where to look.

Comment: If this is some sort of student assignment I can recommend you this https://corevoila.in/landingpost/diffie-hellman-key-exchange-c-sharp-source-code/. If not I would try to rethink the problem because implementing production ready cross platform encryption is no something you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Not a student assignment. I decided to go with BouncyCastle C# API. So far so good. Will update with solution when ready.

Comment: Yes BouncyCastle is a good way to go.